# Проблемы с кодировкой csv

Tags: java, кодировка

Есть CSV-файл, в нём нужно прочитать несколько строк с конца и переслать их на сервер.
При чтении русские буквы некорректно отображаются. Мои попытки изменить кодировку ни к чему не привели, пробовал 5 или 6 разных способов (что в гугле нашёл) - всё бестолку.
Сам CSV файл получен с помощью перевода из формата tps (tps-to-csv.jar, если это даст пользу - гуглите). При переводе, как описано, по стандарту файл CSV кодируется в формате ISO-8859-1. При попытке изменить кодировку во время перевода (есть такая функция) на UTF-8 - русские буквы в CSV-файле уже становятся нечитаемыми.
Вот кусок кода (момент чтения).
Подскажите, как исправить. На всякий случай - [Ссылка на CSV-файл](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4FtW/4XjjtV7Pw)

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int counter = 0;
        String[] arr = new String[100];
        File file = new File("путь к файлу");
        ReversedLinesFileReader object =
                  new ReversedLinesFileReader(file);
        while(counter<100) {
            arr[counter] = object.readLine();
            System.out.println(arr[counter]);
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Посмотрел тот файл. У него кодировка `cp1251` она же `windows-1251`

Comment: чтение файла выполняется в классе ReversedLinesFileReader, добавьте код этого класса.

Comment: ReversedLinesFiileReader находится в apache commons io.
ссылка на официальный сайт https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/